# Amazon s3 – 403 Forbidden with Correct Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, s3cmd

I'm trying to make all of the images I've stored in my s3 bucket publicly readable, using the following bucket policy.

```
{
"Id": "Policy1380877762691",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1380877761162",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

I have 4 other similar s3 buckets with the same bucket policy, but I keep getting 403 errors.

The images in this bucket were transferred using s3cmd sync as I'm trying to migrate the contents of the bucket to a new account.

The only difference that I can see is that

1. i'm using an IAM user with admin access, instead of the root user
2. the files dont have a
   "grantee : everyone open/download file" permission on each of the
   files, something the files had in the old bucket

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that if you have grantee Everyone open/download on the object, you don't need *any* bucket policy to make that work, so your existing policy may in fact be wrong and doing nothing useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **everyone** to access your S3 objects in the bucket, the principal should be "*", i.e., like this:

```
{
"Id": "Policy1380877762691",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1380877761162",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
        "Principal": "*"
        }
    }
]

}
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Principal

Comment: Just tried that, same issue – 403 error Access Denied. I've tried a couple different permutations of that policy all to no avail.

Comment: That's odd. I have similar policies on some of my S3 buckets and it does work. The only difference that I can spot is that you don't have the "Version":"2012-10-17" in your bucket policy. Maybe give that a try?

Comment: Same, on my other buckets the policy works. Something got lost in the transfer between buckets it seems. And aside from the grantee : everyone permissions on each object, nothing else is configured differently.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve it by running the s3cmd command again but adding `--acl-public` to the end of it. Seems to have fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

I Know this is an old question, but for whoever is having this issue and working from the AWS Console. Go to the bucket in AWS S3 console:

1. Open the permissions tab.
2. Open Public Access settings.
3. Click edit

[image]

Then in the editing page :

1. Uncheck Block new public bucket policies (Recommended)
2. Uncheck Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies (Recommended)
3. Click save

[image]

***CAUTION***

PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS WILL MAKE YOUR BUCKET **ACCESSIBLE BY ANYONE ON THE INTERNET**, EVENT IF THEY DO NOT HAVE AN AWS ACCOUNT, THEY STILL CAN ACCESS THE BUCKET AND THE BUCKET'S CONTENTS. **PLEASE HANDLE WITH CAUTION!**

Comment: +1: fixed my issue after I disabled "Block publich and cross-account access". Another option "Block new publich bucket policies" was already disabled to allow to save policy. I am new to AWS, but it helped me to get some progress on static website setup

Answer (score 0):

From AWS Documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure if the order or attributes matter here. I would give this one a try.