# Amazon S3 - Returns 403 error instead of 404 despite GetObject allowance

Tags: amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I've set up my S3 bucket with [this tutorial](https://pete.wtf/2012/05/01/how-to-setup-aws-s3-access-from-specific-ips/) to only accept requests from specific IP addresses. But even though those IPs are allowed to do `GetObject`, they get 403 errors instead of 404 for any files that are missing.

My updated bucket policy is (with fictitious IP addresses):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.bucketname.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "100.100.100.0/22",
                        "101.101.101.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    {
      "Sid": "ListItems",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.bucketname.com",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "100.100.100.0/22",
                        "101.101.101.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
    }
    ]
}
```

(Updated with the `ListBucket` command, as pointed out by Mark B.)

I've found several related questions here on SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037664/how-do-i-have-an-s3-bucket-return-404-instead-of-403-for-a-key-that-does-not-e) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593047/amazon-s3-403-forbidden-with-correct-bucket-policy)), but their solutions are based on giving *everyone* permission to access the bucket's contents.

And that approach works, because if I lift my IP filter then 404 errors are given for missing files instead of 403. But that defeats the purpose of an IP filter.

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037664/how-do-i-have-an-s3-bucket-return-404-instead-of-403-for-a-key-that-does-not-e) that:

> S3 returns a 403 instead of a 404 when the user doesn't have
>   permission to list the bucket contents.

But I cannot find way to have the bucket generate 404 error codes for missing files *without* removing my IP whitelist filter. And that is with including the `GetObject` command for retrieving the objects and `ListBucket` for listing the objects.

My reasoning is as follows: if the IP addresses are allowed to access the bucket's content, then shouldn't S3 generate a 404 error for these IPs instead of 403? How do I do that *without* removing my existing filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem of S3 issuing 403 instead of 404 errors not by changing the bucket policy, but by simply adding an 'Everyone' listing policy in the bucket settings:

[image: New bucket policy]

I feel it's a less elegant than setting the bucket policy, but it at least works now.

My accompanying bucket policy is now still based on only whitelisting a few IPs:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::website-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "10.1.1.0/22",
                        "11.1.1.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you say 'still based on only whitelisting' but the policy document you have seems to be _blacklisting_ IP addresses rather than whitelisting. I guess it was a typo or smth and you meant `IpAddress` instead of  `NotIpAddress`

Answer (score 7):

Note the documentation you quoted:

> S3 returns a 403 instead of a 404 **when the user doesn't have
>   permission to list the bucket contents**.

The `GetObject` permission you have granted only gives permission to get an object that exists, it does not give permission to list all the objects in a bucket. You would need to add the `ListBucket` permission to your bucket policy. See [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) for the full list of S3 IAM permissions, and the S3 operations they cover.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark and sharp noticing. I've added the `ListBucket` permission policy but the same issue still occurs -- I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my computer clock was not set correctly. (because of DST issues)